# Why IE 11 does not append numeric value when we try to open same file multiple times simultaneously

Tags: reporting-services, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I have just migrated from IE 8 to IE 11 for running my SSRS reports. In IE8 whenever I used to export and OPEN (Not Save) a report in excel or csv (only these formats) say XYZ multiple time simultaneously it appended a numeric value in brakets eg. (1), (2)... so there was no issue.

But IE 11 seems does not do this and due to this I get error saying file is already open.

Is there any kind of setting I will have to do in IE 11?

Answer (score 1):

I would choose Save (not Open) - this will create a copy in your default Downloads folder, and will increment the file name number in brackets eg (1), (2).  You will then be prompted (at the bottom of the IE window) to Open the file.

So you will achieve the same process as with IE8, with one extra click.

Comment: Thanks Mike but earlier in IE8 it was there so just wanted to check if that's a setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you click "Open", it overwrites any file in your download folder with the same name.  If you select "Save", it will create a new file name if the file already exists in your download folder. After the file is download you are then prompted what you want to do, at which point you can click "Open".  It's two clicks instead of one... but it works.  The other option is to click the drop down triangle next to "Save" and then select "Save and Open"... but it's still two clicks.  It is Excel that is complaining that it can't open two files with the same name.

I don't know why it changed... maybe because someone decided that when you click "Open" you don't care where the file is saved so you don't care if a file of the same name is overwritten.  If it creates a new name every time you view a file... you could fill your download folder with temporary files that you don't care about.

Comment: Thanks Brian , but our users wanted to have the old functionality. I appreciate your response which even I think is logical but just wanted to see if there is any setting that can be done to do same as IE 8

Comment: /me doing Nick Burns impersonation: "Users........ SIIIIIIIIGH".  :)  If there is a setting it is hidden way too well.  I couldn't find it.